# Problems with React-Native v 0.45.0 on building on XCode

Tags: javascript, react-native, xcode8, build-error

I initialized a react native project. It installed with 0.45.0 version of react-native.

XCode isn't able to build it.

There is a problem with config.hpp file.
[Error is highlighted in red color, which says "'boost/config/user.hpp' file not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvjtv.png)

Answer (score 3):

Been struggling with this issue all day today. Looks like there might be something in the latest version of react-native that is causing the build issues. And I tried just about everything to fix it.

Not sure what the long-term solution is, but I just rolled back to 0.44.0 and that seems to be working for me as a temporary fix.

```
react-native init MyAwesomeApp --version react-native@0.44.0
```

Answer (score 1):

delete $APP_DIR/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4

download glob-0.3.5 from https://github.com/google/glog replace glob-0.3.4